# Difference between parentheses and brackets in Bash conditionals

Tags: bash, if-statement

While learning a bit about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I come to see four types of ways of working with `if` statements:

- Single Parenthesis - ( ... )
- Double Parenthesis - (( ... ))
- Single Square Bracket - [ ... ]
- Double Square Brackets - [[ ... ]]

What is the difference between Parenthesis and Square Brackets in bash.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-conditions-versus-%5B-819433/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The tests you had listed :

- Single Parenthesis - ( ... ) is creating a subshell
- Double Parenthesis - (( ... )) is for arithmetic operation
- Single Square Bracket - [ ... ] is the syntax for the POSIX `test`
- Double Square Brackets - [[ ... ]] is the syntax for bash conditional expressions (similar to `test` but more powerful)

are not exhaustive, you can use *boolean logic*

```
if command; then ...
```

too, because the commands have exit status. In `bash`, `0` is `true` and > `0` is `false`.

You can see the exit status like this :

```
command
echo $?
```

See :

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: `$?` is not exactly the return value, it actually is the exit status; 0 is meant for success and 1 for failure, which you can interpret as true and false.

Comment: Substitued "return value" by "exit status", right, but failure is not only 1 but all status > 0 as written in my post.

Comment: Ex : `curl /dev/null` exit with 3

Comment: @sputnick Actually, failure is all status != 0 -- negative exit values are possible as well.

Comment: @twalberg Negative exit values wrap around - e.g. `exit -1` results in exit value of 255

Comment: 0 is true, non-zero is false — except in arithmetic. `if (( ${?} ))` is false when the exit status is zero, true when non-zero. A bit confusing!

Answer (score 8):

The shell itself only runs the command and evaluates its exit code. A zero exit code signifies success; all other values indicate failure.

```
if command; then
    : things to do if the exit code from command was 0
else
    : things to do if it was not 0
fi

while command; do
    : things to do if the exit code was 0
done
```

The command `[` (aka `test`) is very commonly used in conditionals, because the original Bourne shell lacked built-in operators to check if a string was empty or a file existed. Modern shells have this command built in, and many shells have an extended and modernized version `[[`, but this is not properly portable to POSIX `sh` and should thus be avoided for portable scripts. [This related question](/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) explains the differences between the two in more detail.

The notation `(( ... ))` introduces an arithmetic context. Again, this was something which was not part of the original Bourne shell (it had a dedicated external tool `expr` for these things) but modern shells have this built in. The result code of an arithmetic expression is 0 if the result of the arithmetic evaluation was not 0 (or an error).

The notation `( command )`  creates a subshell and evaluates `command` in that. There are situations where this is actually necessary and useful, but if you are only just learning the syntax, you are unlikely to need this.

...  In fact, in the majority of scripts I have seen this used in a conditional, it was clearly unnecessary.

Another antipattern to look out for is

```
command
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    : things
fi
```

You should almost never need to examine `$?` explicitly, and in particular, comparing it to zero is something `if` and `while` *specifically* do for you behind the scenes. This should simply be refactored to

```
if command; then
    : ...
```