# Differences between [] and () in an "if" condition

Tags: bash, shell

Could someone explain me or point me out some document where the differences between "if () ..." and "if [] ..." can be clarified please?

Comment: () is for specifying function and [ ] for test condition/evaluation ..

Comment: Here is another question where this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765340/difference-in-bash-between-if-statements-with-parenthesis-and-square-brackets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces

Comment: @NSD, `()` in this context would be for running a command pipeline in a subshell and  `if` would act on the exit status.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`if` simply takes an ordinary shell command as an argument, and evaluates the exit code of the command. For example, you can do

```
if grep pattern file; then ...; fi
```

`()` in bash executes the contents in a subshell, so you can specify basically any command in the subshell.

`[]` in bash is a shell command (technically the `[` command), which evaluates an expression according to a specific syntax.

So, `if (...)` is used to test the exit code of a command (in most cases the `()` are redundant), while `if [...]` is used to test an expression using the syntax of `test`.

Comment: Ok, based in your last sentence, can you explain why it is not working? I mean, after "crontab -l > /dev/null 2>&1" $? is 1.

if (crontab -l > /dev/null 2>&1); then
   echo "There is something scheduled"
else
   echo "There is nothing scheduled"
fi

Comment: Forget about it. It was just a logic error! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `[` symbol is actually a command. It is equivalent to the `test` command.

For instance

```
if test "$foo" = 'bar'; then ...
```

is the same as

```
if [ "$foo" = 'bar' ]; then ...
```

Whereas, `if (command)` executes `command` in a subshell.