# Bash script while with boolean and counter

Tags: bash

Can somebody help me with this... I can't seem to get a working while statement (it never enters the loop)...  Tried many different syntaxes and I'm stuck.

```
tries=0
success=false

while (!${success} && ${tries} -lt 10); do
  {
    echo "Trying..." &&
    myCommand &&
    success=true &&
    echo "Success"
  } || {
    success=false &&
    echo "Failed"
  }
  let tries=tries+1
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little change

```
tries=0
success=false

while (( !${success} && ${tries} < 10 )); do
  {
    echo "Trying..." &&
    myCommand &&
    success=true &&
    echo "Success"
  } || {
    success=false &&
    echo "Failed"
  }
  let tries=tries+1
done
```

[Difference in Bash between IF statements with parenthesis and square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765340/difference-in-bash-between-if-statements-with-parenthesis-and-square-brackets)

Comment: Ok, that got me a little bit further.  Thank you... However, there seems to be something wrong with my success=true variable assignment.  The loop doesn't exit on that condition, it executes 10 times whether the command succeeds or not.  Any idea?

Comment: Trivially, `success=0` and `while (( ${success} < 1 && ${tries} < 10 ));` do ... shoud work

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to write C code in `bash`. Specifically, your use of `success` as both a Boolean flag and an executable program is a bit awkward. Try

```
while (( tries < 10 )); do
    { myCommand && echo Success && break; } || { echo Failed && let tries=tries+1; }
done
```

Using an explicit `if` statement would also be more readable:

```
while (( tries < 10 )); do
    if myCommand; then
        echo Success
        break
    else
        echo Failed
        let tries=tries+1
    fi
done
```