# What is the essential difference between compound command and normal command in bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning Bash. Now I'm learning `[[ ... ]]` command and `(( ... ))` command. They are called compound commands, which are different from normal commands like `[`. I read the article of "Compound Commands" in bash manual. It seems they runs with their own rules. But unfortunately, I could not think of why they are called as "compound".
Someone who knows it, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: See: [Difference in Bash between IF statements with parenthesis and square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12765340/3776858)

Comment: You seem to be mixing up terminology big time here.  `((...))` is arithmetic evaluation, not compound commands.  The difference between `[` and `[[` is that the old POSIX `[` is specified elsewhere, and so where Bash wants functionality which differs from POSIX, it can't use that; so there is a separate `[[` built-in which basically overshadows the old `[`.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @tripleee: `man bash` lists them under "Compound Commands" as they have different parsing rules.

Comment: @tripleee : Thank you for comments. And I am sorry for my unclear question. I found ((expression)) and [[expression]] under "Compound Commands" in bash manual. I need to tell you that I know the functional difference between [ and [[. My question is what "compound" means. I can find a word, "compound", in dictionaries but I cannot think of what it actually means in "compound" command. I am just curious why they are called so. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bash distinguishes between simple commands and compound commands:

1. **Simple commands** are a single command with optional arguments and redirections.  For example:

   ```
   $ echo Hello
   Hello
   ```
2. **Compound commands** combine one or more simple commands into something that functions as a single unit.  For example:

   ```
   $ { echo Hello; date; }
   Hello
   Sun Aug 28 23:16:03 PDT 2016
   ```

   One useful feature of compound commands is that redirections applied to the compound command are applied to every command that it contains.  For example:

   ```
   $ { echo info1; echo info2; } >logfile
   $ cat logfile
   info1
   info2
   ```

According to `man bash`, there are four types of compound commands:

1. **Group:** `{...;}`, as illustrated above can be used to group simple commands together to form a compound command.
2. **Subshell:** `(...)` is similar to a group except that the commands are run in subshell environment.  This means that variable assignments do not survive after the subshell completes.  As an example:

   ```
   $ a=0; (a=10; echo "inside=$a"); echo "outside=$a"
   inside=10
   outside=0
   ```
3. **Arithmetic Expression:** Inside double-parens, a series of comma-separated arithmetic calculations may be performed.  For example:

   ```
   $ ((a=2, a=10*a, a+=2)); echo "a=$a"
   a=22
   ```
4. **Test Command:**  Bash's advanced form of the test command, `[[...]]`, can include several tests.  Tests are separated by `&&` or `||`:

   ```
   $ [[ a == b || 3 -gt 2 && 4 -gt 3 ]]; echo $?
   0
   ```

### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> *Compound Commands*
>
> A  compound command is one of the following.  In most cases a list in
>   a command's description may be separated from the rest of the command
>   by one or       more newlines, and may be followed by a newline in
>   place of a semicolon.
>
> `(list)`
>
> list is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION
>   ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin commands  that 
>   affect     the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the
>   command completes.  The return status is the exit status of list.
>
> `{ list; }`
>
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. 
>   This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit
>   status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and }
>   are reserved words and  must  occur              where  a reserved
>   word is permitted to be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word
>   break, they must be separated from list by whitespace or
>   another shell metacharacter.
>
> `((expression))`
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below
>   under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression  is 
>   non-zero,              the return status is 0; otherwise the return
>   status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".
>
> `[[ expression ]]`
>
> Return  a  status  of  0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the
>   conditional expression expression.  Expressions are composed of the
>   primaries              described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS. 
>   Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words
>   between the  [[  and  ]];              tilde  expansion,  parameter 
>   and  variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution,
>   process substitution, and quote removal are              performed. 
>   Conditional operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as
>   primaries.
>
> When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

Comment: Thank you for detailed and clear instruction. I could not contrast simple command with compound command before your answer. That is the reason I was confused. Thank you again.

Comment: @John1024 What is "The return status is the exit status of list."? How is it determined?

Comment: @adosar The exit status of a list is, by default, the exit status of the <i>last</i> command in the list. So, if the last command in the list succeeded (exit status=0), then the exit status of the whole list is set to 0.