# What is the difference between [ test ] and [[ test ]] in bash?

Tags: bash, testing, conditional-statements

What is the difference between [ test ] and [[ test ]] in bash?
When is one more appropriate than the other and what does the `;` at the end do?

```
if  [[ -z $DIRECTORY ]];
then
     DIRECTORY=html
fi

if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    echo installation directory "'${DIRECTORY}'" does not exist
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces) and [What's the difference between \[ and \[\[ in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3427872/218196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.

Comment: `/bin/[` is also functionally equivalent to `/usr/bin/test`.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use single square brackets when we:

- Check something with files and want to use patterns (e.g. asterisk): `if [ -L $file ]; then`
- Check artithmetic expressions: `if [ $a -lt $b ]; then`
- Check something with strings and want to use `" "` and treat special characters as normal (e.g. asterisk): `if [ -z "$string" ]; then`

We usually double square brackets when we:

- Want to use pattern with string (e.g. asterisk): `if [[ "$string1" == *[sS]tring* ]]; then`
- Block patterns in file names (e.g. asterisk) e.g. we search file named *.sh: `if [[ -a *.sh ]]; then`
- Want to use operators && and ||: `if [[ $a == 3 || $b == 4]]; then`
- Don't want to put strings in `" "`

Comment: You make a rather artificial distinction, since everything you list under single brackets can be done with double brackets.

Comment: Of course you're right. It's just wrote the way I remember when to use which brackets :)

Comment: My point is, you don't *need* to use single brackets for any of those. Use single brackets if you are writing code that needs to be POSIX-compatible; use double brackets if your code only needs to run under `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

`[` is for shell, `[[` is for bash.

For example :
Try `[ $A -eq 1 ]`: if `$A` is not set, it raise an error.
`[[ $A -eq 1 ]]` will works.