# Shell spacing in square brackets

Tags: shell, syntax

As a beginner, I did not find answered anywhere, the  rules about spacing (grammar) and parsing.

For example.

Can I do

```
if [$# -eq 2] ; 
then 
    llll 
fi
```

or must I always have a blank or two between the objects, as

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ] ;
then
   llll
fi
```

and the second related question is about the difference between

```
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]] ;
then
wafwaf
fi
```

The concern I have is about spacing before/after `[`, `]`.

No searching has provided me with a set of rules.

Comment: A good way to know what is valid shell grammar and what isn't is to try it.

Answer (score 18):

Spaces are required after `[` and before `]`.

1. `[` is actually the name of a command, an alias for `test`. It's not a special symbol, it's just a command with an unusual name.

   ```
   $ help '['
   [: [ arg... ]
       Evaluate conditional expression.

       This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
       be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
   ```
2. Because it's an ordinary command name and not a special character, a space is required after the `[`. If you omit the space and write `[foo` the shell will search the `$PATH` for a command named `[foo`.

   ```
   $ [ foo = foo ] && echo true
   true
   $ [foo = foo] && echo true
   [foo: command not found
   ```
3. For readability's sake, `[` expects its last argument to be exactly `]`. Being an ordinary command-line argument, `]` must have a space before it. If there's no space then the bracket will become the last character of the previous argument, and `[` will complain about its last argument not being `]`.

   ```
   $ [ foo = foo]
   bash: [: missing `]'
   $ [ foo = 'foo]'
   bash: [: missing `]'
   ```

`[[` is a bash enhancement with more features than `[`, namely saner handling of unquoted variable names. It requires the a space on both ends, same as `[`. However `[[` is in fact special shell syntax and is parsed differently. It's not an "ordinary command" the way `[` is.

For a detailed explanation of the difference between `[` and `[[`, see:

- **[What's the difference between [ and [[ in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931)**

Comment: +1. But perhaps it is worth clarifying that the fact that `[[` is special syntax does not make it self-delimiting. You need spaces (or self-delimiting characters) before and after `[[` and `]]`, just like `[` and `]`. The self-delimiting characters are space, tab and `|&()<>;`. (Which, due to bash's idiosyncrasies is not quite accurate since things like `((` and `>&` are tokens. But it's a good approximation.)