# Shell equality operators (=, ==, -eq)

Tags: bash, shell

What is the difference between `=`, `==` and `-eq` in shell scripting?

Is there any difference between the following?

```
[ $a = $b ]
[ $a == $b ]
[ $a -eq $b ]
```

Is it simply that `=` and `==` are only used when the variables contain numbers?

Answer (score 471, accepted):

`=` and `==` are for string comparisons
`-eq` is for numeric comparisons
`-eq` is in the same family as `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`, and `-ne`

`==` is specific to bash (not present in sh (Bourne shell), ...). Using POSIX `=` is preferred for compatibility. In bash the two are equivalent, and in sh `=` is the only one that will work.

```
$ a=foo
$ [ "$a" = foo ]; echo "$?"       # POSIX sh
0
$ [ "$a" == foo ]; echo "$?"      # bash-specific
0
$ [ "$a" -eq foo ]; echo "$?"     # wrong
-bash: [: foo: integer expression expected
2
```

(Note: make sure to quote the variable expansions. Do not leave out the double-quotes above.)

If you're writing a `#!/bin/bash` script then I recommend [using `[[` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash). The double square-brackets `[[...]]` form has more features, a more natural syntax, and fewer gotchas that will trip you up. For example, double quotes are no longer required around `$a`:

```
$ [[ $a == foo ]]; echo "$?"      # bash-specific
0
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between [ and [[ in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

Answer (score 65):

It depends on the [Test Construct](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) around the operator. Your options are double parentheses, double brackets, single brackets, or [`test`](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html).

If you use [`((`…`))`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html), you are testing arithmetic equality with `==` as in C:

```
$ (( 1==1 )); echo $?
0
$ (( 1==2 )); echo $?
1
```

(Note: `0` means `true` in the Unix sense and a failed test results in a non-zero number.)

Using `-eq` inside of double parentheses is a syntax error.

If you are using [`[`…`]`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) (or single brackets) or [`[[`…`]]`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) (or double brackets), or `test` you can use one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge` as an [arithmetic comparison](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#ICOMPARISON1).

```
$ [ 1 -eq 1 ]; echo $?
0
$ [ 1 -eq 2 ]; echo $?
1
$ test 1 -eq 1; echo $?
0
```

The `==` inside of single or double brackets (or the `test` command) is one of the [string comparison operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

```
$ [[ "abc" == "abc" ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ "abc" == "ABC" ]]; echo $?
1
```

As a string operator, `=` is equivalent to `==`. Also, note the whitespace around `=` or `==`: it’s required.

While you *can* do `[[ 1 == 1 ]]` or `[[ $(( 1+1 )) == 2 ]]` it is testing the string equality — not the arithmetic equality.

So `-eq` produces the result *probably* expected that the integer value of `1+1` is equal to `2` even though the right-hand side is a string and has a trailing space:

```
$ [[ $(( 1+1 )) -eq  "2 " ]]; echo $?
0
```

While a string comparison of the same picks up the trailing space and therefore the string comparison fails:

```
$ [[ $(( 1+1 )) == "2 " ]]; echo $?
1
```

And a mistaken string comparison can produce a completely wrong answer. `10` is *lexicographically* less than `2`, so a string comparison returns `true` or `0`. So many are bitten by this bug:

```
$ [[ 10 < 2 ]]; echo $?
0
```

The correct test for `10` being *arithmetically* less than `2` is this:

```
$ [[ 10 -lt 2 ]]; echo $?
1
```

---

In comments, there is a question about the *technical* reason why using the integer `-eq` on strings returns true for strings that are not the same:

```
$ [[ "yes" -eq "no" ]]; echo $?
0
```

The reason is that Bash is [untyped](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html). The `-eq` causes the strings to be interpreted as integers *if possible* including base conversion:

```
$ [[ "0x10" -eq 16 ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ "010" -eq 8 ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ "100" -eq 100 ]]; echo $?
0
```

And `0` if Bash thinks it is just a string:

```
$ [[ "yes" -eq 0 ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ "yes" -eq 1 ]]; echo $?
1
```

So `[[ "yes" -eq "no" ]]` is equivalent to `[[ 0 -eq 0 ]]`

---

Last note: **Many of the Bash specific extensions to the Test Constructs are not POSIX and therefore may fail in other shells. Other shells generally do not support `[[...]]` and `((...))` or `==`**.

Comment: I'm curious about the *technical reason* for `[[ "yes" -eq "no" ]]` returning True. How does bash coerce these strings to integer values that can be compared? ;-)

Comment: Bash variables are [untyped](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html) so `[[ "yes" -eq "no" ]]` is equivalent to `[[ "yes" -eq 0 ]]`  or `[[ "yes" -eq "any_noninteger_string" ]]` -- All True. The `-eq` forces integer comparison. The`"yes"` is interpreted as a integer `0`; the comparison is True if the other integer is either `0` or the string result is `0`.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: showing (nonportable) `==` in the code samples and only mentioning (portable, standardized) `=` underneath.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: To be fair -- the post is tagged Bash.

Answer (score 31):

`==` is a bash-specific alias for `=` and it performs a string (lexical) comparison instead of a numeric comparison. `eq` being a numeric comparison of course.

Finally, I usually prefer to use the form  `if [ "$a" == "$b" ]`

Comment: Using `==` here is bad form, as only `=` is specified by POSIX.

Comment: If you really insist to use `==` then put it in between `[[` and `]]`. (And make sure that the first line of your script specifies to use `/bin/bash`.)

Comment: @holgero thank you for the thorough and comprehensive explanation.

Comment: What would you do with either $a evaluated to a empty string or $b does?

Comment: @liuliang the double quotes in my comparison are not ceremonial.

Answer (score 25):

Several answers show dangerous examples. The OP's example, `[ $a == $b ]`, specifically used unquoted variable substitution (as of the October 2017 edit). For `[...]` that is safe for string equality.

But if you're going to enumerate alternatives like `[[...]]`, you must inform also that the right-hand-side must be quoted. If not quoted, it is a pattern match! (From the Bash man page: "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.").

Here in Bash, the two statements yielding "yes" are pattern matching, other three are string equality:

```
$ rht="A*"
$ lft="AB"
$ [ $lft = $rht ] && echo yes
$ [ $lft == $rht ] && echo yes
$ [[ $lft = $rht ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ $lft == $rht ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ $lft == "$rht" ]] && echo yes
$
```

Comment: Needs to be `[ "$lht" = "$rht" ]` **with the quotes** to be reliable even for equality. If you have a file created with `touch 'Afoo -o AB'`, `[ $lft = $rht ]` will return true, even though that file name is *not at all* identical to `AB`.