# Bash - Compare variable to string "0"

Tags: bash

The "sync-mongo" file can either contain a git commit id, or 0. When the file contains 0, the if statement still isn't entered.

```
COMMITID=`docker exec -it ${NAME} bash -c 'cd /usr/src/app/_api; cat sync-mongo.commit'`

if [ "${COMMITID}" == "0" ]
then
  ./_configuremongo.sh -i $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -r
fi
```

I've also tried:

```
if [ ${COMMITID} -eq 0 ]
then
  ./_configuremongo.sh -i $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -r
fi
```

which returns `: integer expression expected[: 0`

Comment: And `if [ "$COMMITID" -eq "0" ] `?

Comment: What does `echo "|$commitid|"` show?

Comment: daniu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/bash-equality-operators-eq -eq is for numeric comparisons Barmar 0

Comment: @Asthmatic How can it display only `0`? What happened to the pipes?

Comment: What does `echo "$COMMITID" | od -c` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a `cd` alias that sends an escape sequence, and that's included in the output to `$COMMITID`. Try just using an absolute pathname:

```
COMMITID=`docker exec -it ${NAME} bash -c 'cat /usr/src/app/_api/sync-mongo.commit'`
```

Comment: I think you're right, but abs path didnt fix it. 
Diff between variable and "0":
1c1
< 0
---
> 0;
echo ${COMMITID#0} outputs a blank line (same as just echo)

Comment: Soln was stripping non alphanumeric chars: if [ "${COMMITID//[![:alnum:]]}" == "0" ]