# Can't verify result from SSH

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh

I'm verifying matches of a file via SSH to a host ubunty system, and the if statement is not correctly processing the result.

```
export FILENAME=test.txt
export NUM=$(ssh -t ubuntu@192.168.XXX.XXX "ls ~/Documents/ | grep '$FILENAME' | wc -l")
echo "Received value: $NUM"
if [ $NUM == 0 ]; then
    echo "If processed as: 0"
else
    echo "If processed as: 1"
fi
```

So if `$FILENAME` exists, I get the following output

```
Connection to 192.168.XXX.XXX closed.
Received value: 1
If processed as: 1
```

And if not, I get the following one

```
Connection to 192.168.XXX.XXX closed.
Received value: 0
If processed as: 1
```

Why may this be happening? Am I getting a wrong formatted value? If I force before the if statement `NUM=0` or `NUM=1` it gets correctly processed.

Comment: Try with -eq rather than ==

Comment: I get the following error: `: integer expression expected1`. Anyway, if I set `NUM=0` before the if statement, it works both with `==` or `-eq`. Why may this happen?

Comment: Likely because you are returning more than just a "0" from the SSH command, i.e new line characters or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if [ $NUM == 0 ]; then` should work as expected. ([More info on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/bash-equality-operators-eq))

---

Use `cat -v` to show all invisible chars in your output;

```
NUM=$(ssh -t ubuntu@192.168.XXX.XXX "ls ~/Documents/ | grep '$FILENAME' | wc -l")
echo "NUM: ${NUM}" | cat -v

#Prints; NUM: 0^M
```

The invisible `^M` char is messing with the `if` statement. 
Remove if from the result by piping through `tr -d '\r'`

---

```
export FILENAME=test.txt
export NUM=$(ssh -t ubuntu@192.168.XXX.XXX "ls ~/Documents/ | grep '$FILENAME' | wc -l" | tr -d '\r')
echo "Received value: $NUM"
if [ $NUM == 0 ]; then
    echo "If processed as: 0"
else
    echo "If processed as: 1"
fi
```

---

More `^M` info;

1. [What is `^M`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)
2. [Remove ^M from variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326279/339347)

Comment: Just as a bit more info the ^M is added because the SSH has been requested with tty (-t)

Comment: Wow. I knew it should be related to a hidden character or something, but no idea which one or how to display it. Really nice answer, worked perfectly. Thanks!