# one liner to execute function, check exit status and exit 0 if actual exit code was 0 or 1

Tags: bash, docker, unix, exit, exit-code

I'm running a program where an exit code of either 0 or 1 indicates success. I'm running this while building a docker image, so if the return code is not 0, the build fails. How can I capture the exit code and force an exit code of 0 if the actual exit code is 0 or 1 so that the docker image can properly build?

I've tried something like this where (exit 1) represents the program:

```
((exit 1) && if [ $? == 0 || $? == 1]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi;)
```

but it's not working, an exit code of 1 still exits with 1.

I would rather not do `program || true` in case the program actually does fail for some reason

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `exit 0` has a *truthy*
value, while `exit 1` has a *falsy* value. This means that the right-part of your condition is only executed when the first part is true (because of the `&&` operator).

If your program exits with code 0, you don't have anything to do. However, what you do want is "transform" a code 1 to a code 0. And to do so, the `||` operator is what you need.

This should work:

```
((exit 1) || if [ $? = 1 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi)
```

A few tests to check (I changed the exit code values to better understand what's happening):

```
$> ((exit 0) || if [ $? = 1 ]; then exit 2; else exit 3; fi); echo $?
0  # the right-part of the condition is ignored
$> ((exit 1) || if [ $? = 1 ]; then exit 2; else exit 3; fi); echo $?
2  # the exit code 1 is "converted" into an exit code 2 (or 0 in your case)
$> ((exit 2) || if [ $? = 1 ]; then exit 2; else exit 3; fi); echo $?
3  # the exit code 2 is "converted" into an exit code 3 (or 1 in your case)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that fixed the issue.

Comment: Even simpler, `(exit 1); exit $(( $? > 1 ? $? : 0 ))`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into another problem when implementing this in my dockerfile that I'll note here along with the solution I used just in case anyone else has a similar issue and comes across this.

When I run this:

```
RUN (update_blastdb.pl --decompress taxdb || if [ $? == 1 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi;)
```

I get an error message:

```
Downloading taxdb.tar.gz... [OK]
Decompressing taxdb.tar.gz ... [OK]
/bin/sh: 1: [: 1: unexpected operator
The command '/bin/sh -c (update_blastdb.pl --decompress taxdb || if [ $? == 1 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi;)' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Apparently docker doesn't run the RUN commands using bash by default and you have to add `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` beforehand so that this code can run properly. Then it works.

Comment: This is because "==" is bash specific, but you can simply use "=" instead to be posix-compatible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449556/2679935)

Comment: There always seems to be so many details that I just don't know... x-0 Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know about it either, but I had to look for it to know why you got this message :) On my Linux distribution, `sh` is actually a symbolic link to `bash`, so I never had to care about this before!