# error in executing interactive bash script to run docker containers

Tags: bash, docker

Hello guys i am new in shell scripting and I tried run the script below but have following error message:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the name of the image whose container you want to run: "
read container
echo "Enter a name for this container: "
read name
echo "do you want to run in detatch mode? "
read d
if [ $d -eq yes ]
then
docker run --name $name -P -d $container
elif [ $d -eq no ]
then
docker run --name $name -P $container
else
echo "invalid input"
fi
```

This produces the following error messages:

```
./main.sh: line 9: [: yes: integer expression expected
./main.sh: line 12: [: yes: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-eq` compares two integers
use `=` in order to compare two strings
for more info please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449556/9881735

for example:

```
 [ $d = "yes" ]
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks a million, I have just learned something new