# Bash Read Command Changing Data Type Stored

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, types, zsh

I did try and find the answer online. I cant find inbuilt command to check data type of the read command input.

This is the following script I am noobie creating below. For some reason the comparison is not working when I am inputing int==1.

I have tried comparing to "1" vs 1, but both do not result in True and end up executing the else command?

```
echo "1. Start Session"
echo "2. Entry Here"
echo "3. Entry here"

read option1
echo "you selected" $option1

if [ $option1 == "1" ]
then    
  echo "aaaaaaaaaah!!"
else
  echo "nooooooooo!"
fi
```

Why do I get "noooooo!" and how can I change this to "aaaaaaaaah!"

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What exactly are you entering when prompted? You write `int==1`, but is that what you're typing?

Comment: Try adding `set -x` to your script and running it, this will show you what the contents of your `$option1` variable are at the time of the comparison and might make it clearer why the comparison is failing.

Comment: Note that `==` is not a valid string comparison in baseline /bin/sh; the only POSIX-standardized comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: Also if this is the whole script, add a valid shebang to the top such as `#!/bin/bash` to make sure you're not running as some other shell.

Comment: (also, only tag for one or the other of bash and zsh, never both at once)

Answer (score -1):

For numeric comparision change `==` for `-eq`

E.g

```
echo "1. Start Session"
echo "2. Entry Here"
echo "3. Entry here"

read option1
echo "you selected $option1"

if [ "$option1" -eq 1 ]
then    
  echo "aaaaaaaaaah!!"
else
  echo "nooooooooo!"
fi
```

Your question is answered here:

[Shell equality operators (=, ==, -eq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/shell-equality-operators-eq)

Comment: your answer is totally correct

Comment: Should also be quoting expansions. `"$option1"`, not bare `$option1`

Comment: ...without the quotes, consider what happens if the OP types `-n foobar -o 1` at the prompt; `[ -n foobar -o 1 -eq 1 ]` is true, but you certainly don't _want_ the script to call it success.

Comment: @XT, it's correct as far as it goes, _but_ `test "1" = 1` is true because a comparison between `1` and `1` is also true when compared as strings, not _just_ when they're compared as integers. It'd make a meaningful difference if option1 contained `01` or `001` or something else that's a different string that evaluates to the same number, but we have no reason to believe that to be the case here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy A potential benefit of `-eq` is that you'll get an error if one of the values isn't numeric.

Comment: @Barmar, to be sure, yes. I'm not saying it's not better practice; I'm just saying it's not an adequate explanation for the OP's problem here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do not agree with you

Comment: @XT, don't agree with me about what? That `[ 1 = "1" ]` is true? You can try it yourself; it's not a matter of opinion but simple fact. Or do you disagree that `[ $option1 -eq 1 ]` can incorrectly return true if `option1='-n foobar -o 1'`? Because that's a demonstrably, testably true fact as well (in sh or bash, not zsh).

Comment: (I would also suggest `echo "you selected $option1"`, with the `$option1` _inside_ the double quotes; otherwise, you're prone to the bug described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))

Comment: @CharlesDuffy consider to upvote the answer after correct it.

Comment: @peterpan, the only reason I'm not upvoting is that while the answer describes an improvement to the practices in the OP's code, it doesn't explain why the OP had a problem in the first place. `==` is indeed bad form (as a non-POSIX extension), whereas `=` is the right way to do a string comparison and `-eq` the right way to do a numeric comparison; but if the OP has the value `1` assigned to `option1`, _either_ a string comparison or a numeric comparison should work identically.

Comment: From where I stand, then, this question doesn't have enough information to let others reproduce the stated problem and thus shouldn't be answered at all. (see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).