# Too many arguments on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am getting the error "line 22 : [: too many arguments" on ubuntu server, and I not too sure how to fix it. Just wondering is there any solution for it? Here's my code.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   if [ $name = $ufname ]; then
      echo "Names are still the same"
   fi
fi
```

Comment: $name or $ufname may contain space

Comment: **Quote your string variables** and also add a prefix to prevent against empty string: `[ "z${name}" = "z${ufname}" ]`. That usually takes care of both `empty-string/unitialized` and `space in name` problems.

Comment: I thought quoting also takes care of empty string. bash will pass a placeholder empty-string argument to `[`. right?

Answer (score 2):

One must be very careful with variables that may contain spaces or other special characters. Whitespace can really wrench up the works.

The best solution in bash is to use `[[` instead of `[`. It handles whitespace with grace and style. I recommend just switching to `[[` in all cases and never using `[`. [`[[` is better in all respects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931)

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   if [[ $name = "$ufname" ]]; then
      echo "Names are still the same"
   fi
fi
```

The only reason to use `[` is if portability is a concern--like if you're writing for plain sh rather than bash. In that case, you'll have to stick with `[`, and so you should quote your variables.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   if [ "$name" = "$ufname" ]; then
      echo "Names are still the same"
   fi
fi
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems not working. It wont display the result

Comment: That would be a separate problem. Maybe `$?` isn't 0, or maybe those two variables really aren't equal. Put some printouts in to check.

Comment: By the way, the purpose I am doing this is to match the name from text file with the name from /etc/passwd. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: That's a good question. It's always good to take a step back. You should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Good point, Gordon. I keep forgetting that.