# Shell Scripting; if statement outputting unexpected operator?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to delete 0kb files but the if statement keeps giving me errors, and i'm wondering if you can help me out

I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
EMPTY_FILE=$(find ${1-.} -size 0)
echo $EMPTY_FILE
echo "delete"
read text
if [ "$text" == "yes" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

error is

```
./deleteEmpty.sh: 6: [: yes: unexpected operator
```

Any help on whats wrong is useful! Thanks

Comment: This appears to work for me. That is, if I run that script, and type "yes", I get "yes" back. Is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: Hm.. it doesn't work for me. is there something i need to install/change for this to work? Edit: oh man, i used /sh instead of bash

Comment: You are the `test` command in which you should use `=` for string comparison instead of `==`. If you are using bash, then `==` would be fine too.

Comment: If you do switch your shebang to bash, use `read -p "delete? " text` -- and pick a better variable name.

Answer (score 3):

In plain sh the equality operator is `=`. `==` is a bashism. Either change your shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`, or change the test to:

```
if [ "$text" = "yes" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

If you use bash, [I recommend using `[[` instead of `[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $text == yes ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double brackets:

```
if [[ "$text" == "yes" ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use bash. In that case the first line of your script should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```