# What are these bash_profile functions doing?

Tags: shell, bash

I'm confused about this conditional:

```
 if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]
```

What is this language?

Here is what I'm familiar with for my terminal and bash_profile:

> Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter, for the GNU
>   operating system.

and

> Simply put, the shell is a program that takes your commands from the
>   keyboard and gives them to the operating system to perform. In the old
>   days, it was the only user interface available on a Unix computer.
>   Nowadays, we have graphical user interfaces (GUIs) in addition to
>   command line interfaces (CLIs) such as the shell.
>
> On most Linux systems a program called bash (which stands for Bourne
>   Again SHell, an enhanced version of the original Bourne shell program,
>   sh, written by Steve Bourne) acts as the shell program.

```
function parse_git_branch {
    branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null`
    if [ "HEAD" = "$branch" ]; then
      echo "(no branch)"
    else
      echo "$branch"
    fi
  }

  function prompt_segment {
    # for colours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors
    # change the 37 to change the foreground
    # change the 45 to change the background
    if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
      echo "\[\033[${2:-37};45m\]${1}\[\033[0m\]"
    fi
  }

  function build_mah_prompt {
    # time
    ps1="$(prompt_segment " \@ ")"

    # cwd
    ps1="${ps1} $(prompt_segment " \w ")"

    # git branch
    git_branch=`parse_git_branch`
    if [[ ! -z "$git_branch" ]]
    then
      ps1="${ps1} $(prompt_segment " $git_branch " 32)"
    fi

    # next line
    ps1="${ps1}\n\$ "

    # set prompt output
    PS1="$ps1"
  }

  PROMPT_COMMAND='build_mah_prompt'
```

Comment: `-z`: see: `help -m test | less`

Comment: Thanks for `help` command. :-) I always used to go to `man bash` & then search for the required word... :-/

Comment: help -m test | less shows me an empty screen with just the end keyword in it in vim.

Answer (score 2):

The language is Bash, a modern shell based on the old Bourne shell and
(mostly) compatible with [POSIX standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

#### test aka [

`[[` is a Bash extension of the `test` command also known as `[`.  The `test` command is a separate executable but since it’s so useful for shell programming, most (if not all) modern shells implement it as a shell builtin.  The following commands show that both versions are available on many systems:

```
$ type -a test
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test

$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

For more info, see `man test` or `help test` (with Bash).

#### `[[`

`[[` is implemented as a Bash keyword (not an external command). It originally came from the [Korn shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) and works similarly but has many improvements over the original `[` command. See the following for more info:

- [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)
- [What's the difference between [ and [[ in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931)
- [Is [[ ]] preferable over [ ] in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts/669486#669486)

#### Specific example

According to `man test` (POSIX specification)

> `−z string` True if the length of string string is zero; otherwise, false.

Thus, the `[[ -z "$1" ]]` construct returns `0` (value for `True` in Unix shells) if `$1`, the first positional parameter to a script or function is an empty string.  Introducing the negation `!` operator converts the expression to its Boolean opposite, i.e, `False` if the following expression evaluates to `True` and vice versa.

To sum up, the whole expression evaluates to `True` if the first argument to the function is a non-empty string and `False` if it’s empty (or possibly not set at all).

If you read the above links, you’ll notice that `[[ ! -z "$1" ]]` is actually equivalent to `[[ -n "$1" ]]` which return `True` if `$1`contains anything, i.e., is *not empty*. This can be further shortened to `[[ $1 ]]` as quotes aren’t required for variables within `[[`.

Note: the portable version (for POSIX shells) is `[ -n "$1" ]` or `[ "$1" ]` (where the variables have to be quoted to protect from pathname expansion, word splitting and other potential side effects). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more info.

#### Functions

The remaining code are shell functions which look like they’re used to build up a colourful prompt which provides details of the status of a git repository if the current working directory is under version control.

Comment: This can even be shortened to `[[ $1 ]]` (careful, you have a space missing—and the quotes are unnecessary (though harmless)).

Comment: Quotes are not here to prevent from variables containing `-n` (for example, `[ -n ]` works as expected: returns `0` (true)—it's a special case of the `test` statement with a single argument); quotes are here to protect from pathname expansion and word splitting.

Comment: `[` is an ordinary command (whether or not it is implemented as a built-in), so all the regular rules of expansion apply to its argument(s). `[[ ... ]]`, however, is similar to what is called a special form in Lisp; it has its own rules for how the expression inside is evaluated. In particular, you can treat it as if `[[` itself performs the parameter expansion, letting it interpret the values directly, rather than having the shell expand them and passing the result *to* `[[`.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan clarify this: 'Accordingly, [[ -z "$1" ]] construct returns 0 (True) if $1, the first positional parameter is an empty string. However, the addition of the ! operator returns the negated value (False instead of True).'

Comment: 0 is a true value in UNIX shells and -z does some kind of 0 or 1 conversion it seems?

Comment: @Jwan622 It's the `!` negation operator that converts the value to its opposite.

Comment: What does the -z do though? It seems like it converts a value to 0 or 1. "the [[ -z "$1" ]] construct returns 0 (value for True in Unix shells) if $1, the first positional parameter to a script or function is an empty string." So if $1 is the string "hello" which is perhaps truthy in Bash, the -z converts it to 0 which is True in Unix shells right?

Comment: The documentation for `-z` is quoted in the answer.