# In bash shell, how to classify the usage of (), (()),[], [[]] and {}?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell. And I'm a little bit confused with the usage of (),[],{} in shell script like `$()` ,`[ [] ]`, `${}` and so on. I want to classify their usage to learn shell script more efficiently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[ ]` vs `[[ ]]` are [**test operators**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)
 See [What's the difference between [ and [[ in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427931/1983854) for a good overview on their differences.

`$()` is [**command substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

```
$ echo "my hostname is: $(hostname)"
my hostname is: MYPC
```

`$(( ))` is [**arithmetic expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

```
$ echo "$(( 5 + 5 ))"
10
```

`${ }`
  This is used to refer to variables and avoid confusion over their name.

```
$ v="hello"
$ echo "$vbye"

$ echo "${v}bye"
hellobye
```

Also, it is used to reference array elements:

```
$ declare -A my_arr
$ my_arr[a]="hello"
$ echo "${my_arr[a]}"
hello
```

`( )` and `{ }` are also used as [grouping commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

`( )` runs in a subshell:

```
$ v=5
$ ( v=2; echo "$v" )
2
$ echo "$v"
5
```

Whereas `{ list, }` does not:

```
$ v=5
$ { v=2; echo "$v"; }
2
$ echo "$v"
2
```