# Bash script: too many arguments in [ test ]

Tags: linux, bash, testing, quoting

I have the bash script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
[ $# -eq 1 -a $1 = "--help" -o $# -eq 0 ] && {
  echo Help will come here
}
```

When I run it:

```
$ ./script 
./script: line 3: [: too many arguments
$ ./script --help
Help will come here
```

As you can see, when I don't pass parameters ( $# -eq 0 ) it fails with "too many arguments".
So, I tested it directly in terminal:

```
$ a=1;b=2;c=3
$ [ $a -eq 1 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 3 ] && echo ok
ok
$ [ $a -eq 0 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 3 ] && echo ok
ok
$ [ $a -eq 0 -a $b -eq 0 -o $c -eq 3 ] && echo ok
ok
$ [ $a -eq 0 -a $b -eq 0 -o $c -eq 0 ] && echo ok
$ [ $a -eq 0 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 0 ] && echo ok
$ [ $a -eq 1 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 0 ] && echo ok
ok
```

So, if it works perfectly in terminal why doesn't it work passing parameters?

Thanks,

Comment: Use more quotes: `[ $# -eq 1 -a "$1" = "--help" -o $# -eq 0 ]` (see the quotes around the variable expansion `"$1"`?).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Why not just use `$# -eq 0 -o "$*" = "--help"`?

Comment: @l'L'l: my point was only about the quotes. There are better answers below `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, thank you, you were right about the quotes, I totally forgot them, and I think you were the first to mention it. If you had put as an answer I would've ticked yours as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire expression can be simplified to:

```
function help () {
    printf "%s\n" "help is on it's way."
}

[[ $# -eq 0 || "$*" = "--help" ]] && help ; echo "done." && exit 0 ;
```

This checks if the total sum of arguments is zero, or the argument(s) equals "--help". If either of those two things are true then it proceeds to the `help` function, otherwise echo "done" and exit.

Comment: This works beautifully @l'L'l. I don't quite understand the difference between [] and [[]]. From what I know [] is a short for the command test.

Comment: @Adriano_epifas: In short, `[[` is bash's improvement to the `[` notation. Here's a detailed comparison: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3427931/499581

Comment: You're welcome! `[[` and `[` are actually "test commands" not really "notation" as mentioned... ;_;

Answer (score 3):

Express your condition like this :

```
[ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "--help" ] || [ $# -eq 0 ]
```

Actually, `[` is a command, and the following elements in the commands are subject to word splitting.  If an argument is empty (or contains whitespace and is unquoted), you can run into surprises.  Using `-a` and `-o` is deprecated.

Please note that, if you want to use the `&&` logical operator (instead of an `if` statement) before your `echo` statement, you will need to enclose the above inside braces, else the operator precedence (coupled with lazy evaluation) may yield incorrect results.

```
{ [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "--help" ] || [ $# -eq 0 ] ; } && { echo...
```

If you do not mind using Bash-specific syntax, you could also write :

```
[[ $# -eq 1 && $1 = "--help" || $# -eq 0 ]]
```

Note that in this case, double-quoting `$1` is not required, because the `[[ ]]` construct is special shell syntax, not a command, and what is inside is not subject to word splitting.  Because there is a single test, you do not need to enclose it inside braces before your `&& { echo...`.

Comment: Re: "[[ ]] construct is special shell syntax, not a command, and what is inside is not subject to word splitting", is perhaps not entirely correct. https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2048. In shellcheck.net using an unquoted `$@` or `$*` prompts this warning while used inside `[[ ]]`, so this may be an exception.

Comment: @l'L'l From the Bash manual : "Word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]"

Comment: It's interesting that the warning comes up on shellcheck.net; I wonder if that should be reported.

Comment: Still from the manual, in the section about `$@` : "When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.".  This invaluable behavior, also available for array expansions, can be a little counter-intuitive at first, because double quotes usually enclose a string that will be considered a single word.  It should be understood as "expand all arguments, but make sure each argument stays a single word by not submitting it to word splitting".

Comment: In shellcheck when trying to use `[[ $@ ]]` it comes back with `^-- SC2199: Arrays implicitly concatenate in [[ ]]. Use a loop (or explicit * instead of @).`, and then while using `[[ $* ]]` it returns `^-- SC2048: Use "$@" (with quotes) to prevent whitespace problems.`, so it is a bit confusing.

Comment: I do not remember using `$@` inside a test (quoted or not), and I am not sure it would make sense to do so...  But if I try `set -- 1 2 3 ; [[ "$@" ]]` I get no error, whereas `[[ 1 2 3 ]]` fails.  So "$@" is either never expanded to several words, or is first but then is concatenated (could be linked to the shellckeck warning).

Comment: I would say the moral of the story is : do not use `$@` in tests, perform an assignment outside the test first to get what you actually want inside a string, and then perform the test on that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing the script without parameter, you are getting the error because your condition is matching with blank character, see below -

```
$sh -x kk.sh 
+ '[' 0 -eq 1 -a = --help -o 0 -eq 0 ']'
kk.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments
```

As you can see that there is no value to match.

When you will execute below command in your terminal -

```
$[ $a -eq 1 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 3 ] && echo ok
-bash: [: too many arguments
$a=1;b=2;c=3
$[ $a -eq 1 -a $b -eq 2 -o $c -eq 3 ] && echo ok
ok ####it is printing this value bcoz you have set the variable to match, it doesn't matter condition is wrong or right but there is something to match.
```

To resolve this issue you can use one if condition in the beginning to assign a dummy value if there is no value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

[ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $1 = "--help" ] || [ $# -eq 0 ]

This way it will automatically display if --help is provided or 1 is typed.

I think $# is creating the problem as both there is $# for first and second conditions

Comment: `$1` should be quoted, because an empty value or one with whitespace would cause the test to fail due to an incorrect number of arguments after word splitting.

Comment: Reuse of `$#` in two conditions is not the problem here, it is actually required to get the behavior I assume is expected by the OP.

Comment: The logical operator between the first two tests should be `&&`.

Comment: what @Fred said is right. the problems was that I didn't quote $1. Thank you