# Shell conditional errors out - Bash syntax not recognized

Tags: bash, shell, dash-shell

I have a little shell script and cannot seem to figure out how to create a simple conditional statement.

```
big_width=$(($width > 1700))
big_height=$(($height > 1700))

if [ $extension != "jpg" || $big_width || $big_height ]; then
```

Gives the errors

```
[: missing ]
0: not found
```

Also IDK if this will give me what I want. The coniditional should be executed if `$extension != "jpg` or if one of the width/height variables are bigger than 1700.

#### Edit

Trying this code `if [[ $extension != "jpg" ]] || ((width > 1700)) || ((height > 1700)); then` gives a `height: not found error`. Any idea why the bash syntax is erroring out?

#### Edit

When I add this to my script

```
echo $0
echo $SHELL
```

It prints

```
source/images/shrink_img.sh
/bin/bash
```

So bash should be working right? I have no idea why this conditional syntax breaks things. I have tried changing file extensions from `.sh` to `.bash` and calling the script with `bash` instead of `sh` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, this piece of code will do the trick. You can also play around if you want to change the conditions.

```
    width=1701
    height=1699
    extension="jpg"

    if [ $extension != "jpg" ] || [ $width -gt 1700 ] || [ $height -gt 1700 ]; 
    then
        echo "Yay"
    else
        echo "Nay"
    fi
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks. Any idea why John Kugleman's solution wasnt' working?

Comment: Some issues I see with John's suggestion. 1. "[" is a conditional statement - that is not used except for first condition. 2. Variables used lack "$". 3. ">" used instead of "-gt".                                      
Shell is also very sentimental about spaces especially for conditions but I see that John has been careful with that.

Comment: None of those are issues. Inside `((...))` variables don't need `$`, and `>` is the correct operator. When using bash it's better to use `[[` and `((` rather than `[` (single bracket).

Comment: James, if this works and my answer doesn't, it really seems like your "bash" shell isn't actually bash because you're saying all my bash-isms don't work. `[` is an older sh-compatible syntax. You shouldn't have to fall back to it in proper bash.

Comment: I agree John. I tried to add the bounty and changed the question title to try and figure out why the bash syntax isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

In C you can put a bare `0` or `1` where a boolean expression is expected. Not so in shell scripts. You also cannot use `&&` and `||` inside of single square brackets. They need to be outside.

**Option 1:** Write all three tests explicitly.

```
if [[ $extension != "jpg" ]] || ((width > 1700)) || ((height > 1700)); then
```

**Option 2:** Use "boolean" variables.

```
((big_width  = width  > 1700))
((big_height = height > 1700))

if [[ $extension != "jpg" ]] || ((big_width)) || ((big_height)); then
```

**Option 3:** Hide the tests behind functions.

```
big_width () { ((width  > 1700)); }
big_height() { ((height > 1700)); }

if [[ $extension != "jpg" ]] || big_width || big_height; then
```

(You'll notice that I switched to double square brackets. `[[ ... ]]` is more robust than `[ ... ]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931) for an in depth explanation of the advantages of double brackets.)

Comment: Trying to use option 1 gives me `314: not found`, or whatever my `width` is.

Comment: I added `$` in front of width/height vars. If that isn't there then I receive `height: not found` issues. Other than that, it was a copy/paste. No idea why it's not working. Other methods aren't working either.

Comment: `$` is optional for variables referenced inside `((...))`. Are you for sure in bash? Do you have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang line at the top of your script?

Comment: Yes, and I am calling it via `bash script.sh vars`. Not sure if that for sure means I am in bash though.

Comment: You can't use `||` inside `[...]`, but you can use it inside `[[ ... ]]` and `(( ... ))`.

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit @chepner? It looks like the `||` are outside of any brackets, what would be the correct way to write it?

Comment: `((width > 1700)) || ((height > 1700))` and `((width > 1700 || height > 1700))` both work. If you had multiple `[[ ... ]]` conditions you could likewise combine them. You can't do that with single `[ ... ]` though, only double brackets.

Comment: Ah ok, I can see that you all were talking about the OP, and I was referring to the revisions made as suggested by John. We're all on the same page now. Any idea why using John's answer is erroring out for me?

Comment: @JamesLowrey It really sounds like you aren't actually running the script with `bash`.

Comment: I agree. Any ideas why that might be, given my shebang is correct and I am calling it via `bash script vars`?

Comment: I'll be honest, I've got no idea. You might want to open another question so you can show exactly what you're trying to run and what's happening. Make sure to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The `or` operator is `-o`, and you need to use comparison `-eq 0`:

```
big_width=$(($width > 1700))
big_height=$(($height > 1700))

if [ $extension != "jpg"  -o  $big_width -eq 0  -o  $big_height -eq 0 ]; then
```

Comment: `-o` has been marked obsolescent, see [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). See also [Tests and conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) in the Wooledge wiki, under "good practice".