# Why do some people put a semicolon after an if condition in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm just getting used to shell scripting, and I've come across something which I'm not really sure how to google.

In the tutorials I was reading, it suggests that the correct way to write an if statement is like this:

```
if [ $a == $b ]; then
  echo "a == b"
fi
```

However I've seen in our code base places where the semi colon is omitted:

```
if [ $a == $b ] then
  echo "a == b"
fi
```

I've also seen double square brackets:

```
if [[ $a == $b ]]; then
  echo "a == b"
fi
```

When I've tested all of these in bash, there doesn't seem to be a difference.  Is there a difference?  Does it have to do with compatibility?  What is the correct style to adopt?

Comment: This might help: `help if`

Comment: For [ vs [[, look at this page: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29, section 4. Conditional Blocks

Comment: One other minor note is that `==` is a bash-specific comparison operator. Using just one `=` is the POSIX-compliant way of comparing strings. You likely also want to double-quote your variables to avoid unintended word-splitting, so `if [ "$a" = "$b" ]`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
if [ $a == $b ]; then
  echo "a == b"
fi
```

You can use a semicolon, or you can write `then` on a separate line. Either one is allowed.

```
if [ $a == $b ]
then
  echo "a == b"
fi
```

Having neither a `;` nor a newline is a syntax error.

```
$ if [ $a == $b ] then
>   echo "a == b"
> fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

As for `[` vs `[[`, see:

- [What's the difference between [ and [[ in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/3427931#3427931)