# Command online argument in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Hi I have written small shell script, I am not able to understand the behavior of that script. can any one help me to understand that script.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]
then
   echo "fail"
else
  echo "success"
fi
```

While executing  the script .

```
./test.sh one
```

It exuting the else statement instead of main statement , even though its passing the argument.

can any one explain me this behavior to understand

Comment: Please see the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) for the list of which conditional expression flags perform which action.

Comment: So your question is "What does `-z` mean?"

Comment: If I answered your question it would be nice if you would mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The `-z` test in bash is checking if a string is an empty (zero length) value.

Since you're passing an argument to the script `$1` is not empty and therefore `-z $1` evaluates to `false`, executing the `else` portion of your script.

Side note: Since you're working with strings I recommend you to quote variables as follows:

```sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "String is empty / No argument given"
else
    echo "String is not empty / Argument given"
fi
```

---

Edit:
As pointed out by [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) it's probably better to use `[[` instead of `[`. This, among others, eliminates the need for quoting. See more differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427931/9138821).

```sh
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    ...
```

However, be aware that this is a bash extension and won't work in sh scripts.

Comment: Also adding... the `[` command is a synonym for the `test` command. You can learn more about the flags available for `test` by looking at it's manual: `man test`. Where you will see `-z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero`

Comment: Hi Jnevill. Thank you for your response

Comment: @confetti: Wouldn't it maybe better to recommend the `[[ ... ]]` form of the test? We wouldn't have to care about quoting then.

Comment: @user1934428 I've made an edit and added some background information.