# Check multiple files having size greater than zero in KornShell

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, file-handling

Below is a simple script to find out whether all files exists and are having size greater than zero or not. From [here](http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/bash-shell-scripting-check-file-exists-not/) I know '-s' is used for the task.

```
if [ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3}]; then
   echo "present"
   echo "Perform analysis"
else
   echo "not present";

   echo "Value of file1: `-s ${file1}`"
   echo "Value of file2: `-s ${file2}`"
   echo "Value of file3: `-s ${file3}`"
   echo "skip";
fi
```

The files are present on the path same as the script. I have checked the files names and it is correct. I am getting the following error :

```
./temp.ksh[]: [-s: not found [No such file or directory]
not present
./temp.ksh[]: -s: not found [No such file or directory]
Value of file1:
./temp.ksh[]: -s: not found [No such file or directory]
Value of file2:
./temp.ksh[]: -s: not found [No such file or directory]
Value of file3:
```

I can't seem to find out what's wrong with above. Is this specific to KornShell? I can only use KSH.

Comment: You need an extra space between the closing square bracket. `if [ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3} ];`

Comment: I tried adding extra space. Now the error is ./temp.ksh[]: [: ']' missing
Between.... echo should work at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) question's answer. The error is using [ ] in if statement instead of [[ ]] as [[ ]] can interpret  && but [ ] can't.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the `test` command which is also written as `[ Conditional Expression ]`. Conditional expressions can be written inside a `test` command but not used as an executable statement.

So **don't do**

```
echo "Value of file1: `-s ${file1}`"
```

But **do**

```
echo "Value of file1: $( [[ -s ${file1} ]] && echo 0 || echo 1)"
```

Also, the `-s` does not return the size, but checks if the size is zero or not as a return code.

Furthermore, the `test` command does not know `&&` (as mentioned by [Ankit Chauhun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870864/8344060)).

So **don't do**

```
if [ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3} ]; then
```

But **do** any of

```
if [ -s ${file1} ] && [ -s ${file2} ] && [ -s ${file3} ]; then
if [[ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3} ]]; then
```

You might be interested in:

```
if [[ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3} ]]; then
   echo "present"
   echo "Perform analysis"
else
   echo "not present";

   stat --printf="Value of file1: %s" "$file1"
   stat --printf="Value of file2: %s" "$file2"
   stat --printf="Value of file3: %s" "$file3"
   echo "skip";
fi
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. But the echo output is blank and for if statement it is :  ./temp.ksh[]: [: ']' missing     . I also printed the file names and tried to cat  the same name and I am able to see the contents of file.

Comment: Now I am getting 0 in echo which you suggested after **But do**. But for the if statement it is still giving me same error which I mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers look good to me but I had to try it just to see.
This works for me:

```
file1=a.txt
file2=b.txt
file3=c.txt

if [[ -s ${file1} && -s ${file2} && -s ${file3} ]]
then
    echo "present"
    echo "Perform analysis"
else
    echo "not present";

    for name in ${file1} ${file2} ${file3}
    do
        if [[ ! -s ${name} ]]
        then
            date > ${name}  # put something there so it passes next time
            echo "just created ${name}"
        fi
    done
    echo "skip";
fi
```

I put that into a file called checkMulti.sh and got the following output:

```
$ ksh checkMulti.sh
not present
just created a.txt
just created b.txt
just created c.txt
skip
$ ksh checkMulti.sh
present
Perform analysis
$ rm a.txt
$ ksh checkMulti.sh
not present
just created a.txt
skip
$ ksh checkMulti.sh
present
Perform analysis
```

The use of single brackets [ went away with ksh 88.  I suggest always using double [[ these days.

Also, check to make sure you have spaces before and after the brackets and before the dashs.  I just tried to reproduce your error and got (this is wrong):

```
$ if [[-s fail]]   #<<< missing space before -s and after filename
> then
> echo yes
> fi
-ksh: [[-s: not found [No such file or directory]
$
```

But if I put in the spaces that are needed (and create a file) I get:

```
$ date > good  # put something in a file
$ if [[ -s good ]]
> then
>     echo yes
> fi
yes
$
```