# Codacy analyzer warning: In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined

Tags: bash, shell, analyzer, codacy, shellcheck

When I run `codacy-analysis-cli analyze` command for the next line of script:

```sh
if [[ "$lexer_date" > "$lexer_ts_date" ]]; then
    generate_grammar
fi
```

I got the next warning:
`` Found [Warning] `In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.` in scripts/grammar.sh:20 (shellcheck_SC2039) ``

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't use `[[` with `/bin/sh`? The warning is true. `[[` is a feature the `sh` standard doesn't specify, so `/bin/sh` isn't guaranteed to provide it. If you want features that are only added in extended shells like ksh or bash, you need to use an extended shell like ksh or bash.

Comment: Beyond that, it's not clear what kind of answer you want.

Comment: ...that said, you might find [What is the difference between `[` and `[[` in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) useful.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy. I take a look your link.
I just wanna to fix warning and looking for alternatives.

Comment: The _best_ alternative is to stop trying to use `/bin/sh` if you need features it doesn't offer, and switch to ksh or bash instead. `[[` exists for a reason (in that many of the features it offers over `[` are impossible without syntax extensions, and `[` is required to be parsed like a regular command, not like syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[` instead. Note that for alphanumeric comparisons you need to quote the comparison operator; thus:

```
if [ "$lexer_date" ">" "$lexer_ts_date" ]; then
    generate_grammar
fi
```

Comment: The operator needs to be quoted? Is it seen as a redirection otherwise?