# Healthcheck shell script: $$? vs $? in elasticsearch docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, bash, elasticsearch, curl, docker-compose

I was reading the elasticsearch documentation on [Elastic Stack on Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html) with TLS.

I came across this line in the healthcheck block:

```sh
curl --cacert $CERT_PATH/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null
if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then
   echo 0
else
   echo 1
fi
```

The script uses the CA cert in the specified directory to verify the peer.

I know that `$?` is the exit status of the most recent foreground pipeline (curl in this case). My question is why are there  2 `$` in the `[[...]]` test command construct. I tried removing the 1 `$`, but then Docker complains about an invalid interpolation format for the health check option ...

Does the 1st `$` serve some specific purpose in docker-compose files or is `$$?` in itself some special shell variables?

Link to the full [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docs/blob/master/docs/en/getting-started/docker/elastic-docker-tls.yml) on elastic's Github repo. The above line corresponds to line 38 in the linked docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Why did you try to remove a `$` ? Does the docker-compose fail when you execute it ?

Comment: I removed the 1st `$` just to see if it will work. Because the test is to see if `curl` returns status code 52. What I don't get is that if `$?` means the exit status of the previous program why does the script use `$$?` And yes, docker-compose failed to start when I removed the 1st `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in docker nor elasticsearch.
Perhaps this has less to do with `bash` than with `make`.

To get a `$` in a `makefile` it must be escaped with an additional `$`. So to get `$?` in a makefile you need `$$?`.

On the other hand in bash `$$` gets you the pid of the current process, so of the bash.

Comment: This seems to make a lot of sense. However, why isn't \ used for escaping? Also, what shell do you use when you're running your makefile. Do you use `[...]` or `[[...]]` for the test construct? Just want to iron out all other possibilities.

Comment: There is no Makefile here. You can use either `[` or `[[` depending on what you want; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Comment: on up for tripleee. While there is no Makefile there, the mechanism behind it might be inspired by one. If you run a script like that, I try to stick with POSIX and `sh`.