# Check to see if Java is installed via Bash not working

Tags: java, linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm automating some things via bash and one of the things I wish to do is only execute a certain command if a condition is false.

I have written this little script to check the existence of java on a machine and then, if it doesn't exist, install java on the machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

java_path=$(which java) 
if [ "$java_path" = "/usr/bin/java" ]; then
    printf "\nJava Installed, version:\n"
    java -version
else
    printf "\nJava Not Installed, Installing...\n"
    #sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
    java -version
fi
```

My problem is that the code always goes down the *else* path, even though when I execute `which java` via commandline, I get `usr/bin/java`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if type -P java >/dev/null; then java --version; else ....; fi` , see `help type` for more info.

Comment: Are you sure you get `usr/bin/java` and not `/usr/bin/java`? per the other comment, `type` is better here.

Comment: Also, no need to compare `java_home` var, just checking it's not empty should work: `if [ -n "$java_path" ]`

Comment: @Jetchisel what is the ">/dev/null doing?

Comment: Not to print the output to `stdout` since the exit status is enough in scripting.

Comment: In Unix/Linux you can have several executables in different directories but same name,  so testing the absolute path will not give  you a correct info. Try this `which cd`

Comment: @LMC If java isn't installed wouldn't the shell still return some text, thereby causing the check to always go to the if branch rather than else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status of `which` can be used in the if-else statement, no need to save the output.

```
if which java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    java -version
else
    echo "Java not installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if [[ $(which java) == "/usr/bin/java" ]]
then
    printf "\nJava Installed, version:\n"
    java -version
else
    printf "\nJava Not Installed, Installing...\n"
fi
```

Since you assume java will be in /usr/bin, you consider only the installation via the official package.  You could check if the package is installed instead.

To cover all cases, you could:

- check if the package is installed.
- check if `which java` returns something.
- run a `find` to see if it is somewhere else on the system.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However (I'm new to bash) why are there double square brackets in the if condition?

Comment: Many threads explain it, start with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Comment: Got it. However, upon running your code, it's still printing "Java Not installed", even though it is.

Comment: Also I tried changing "$(which java)" to "/usr/bin/java" to make sure string comparison is working and it is.

Comment: What does `which java` return?  You might have to modify the comparison text to match that particular value.